# How to declare cursor on conditional base in after insert trigger (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, triggers, cursor

My trigger is here.

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_demo`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `done` BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    ->   DECLARE `_id` INT;
    ->   DECLARE `_value` VARCHAR(50);
    -> 
    ->   DECLARE `demo_cursor` CURSOR FOR
    ->   SELECT * -- <- SELECT `id`, `value` Recommendation for use
    ->   FROM `tbl_demo`
    ->   WHERE `id` = NEW.`id`;
    ->   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done` := TRUE;
    -> 
    ->   OPEN `demo_cursor`;
    -> 
    ->   `read_loop`: LOOP
    ->     FETCH `demo_cursor` INTO `_id`, `_value`;
    -> 
    ->     IF `done` THEN
    ->       CLOSE `demo_cursor`;
    ->       LEAVE `read_loop`;
    ->     END IF;
    -> 
    ->     INSERT INTO `result_demo`
    ->       (`id`, `value`)
    ->     VALUES
    ->       (`_id`, `_value`);
    ->   END LOOP;
    -> END//
```

I wish to declare **demo_cusror** as per NEW field value something like

```
if NEW.`id`=NULL THEN
   DECLARE `demo_cursor` CURSOR FOR SELECT * tbl_demo ;
ELSE
   DECLARE `demo_cursor` CURSOR FOR SELECT * tbl_demo2;
END IF
```

I tried but i can not put if condition on declaration part.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare any variables conditionally in mysql. Period. As mysql documentation on [declare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) says:

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Declare 2 cursor variables and decide in the application logic which one to use.